# can't craft a zoomed out map in minecraft 1.11.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try and use the zoom out map recipe I am given 9 versions of my current map, and I cant seem to find any way to zoom them out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to surround the map with paper instead of other maps. Including other blank maps just clones the map, but paper extends the map.